# how to disable button in flutter

Tags: flutter, api, button, disable

I have an elevated button, to which i want to disable it after user hits the button, api gets called here.  i have tried to setState but itseems not working. what else can i do to disable button.

hint: my concept i am working is that once ther users clicks the button, again the user should not be able to click again the same button.

Here is my code:

```
bool isEnable = false;
     ElevatedButton.icon(
                  style: ButtonStyle(
                      backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(
                          const Color.fromARGB(255, 53, 121, 87)),
                      padding:
                          MaterialStateProperty.all(const EdgeInsets.all(20)),
                      textStyle: MaterialStateProperty.all(const TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 14, color: Colors.black))),
                  onPressed: qrdata.code != 9 && !isEnable 
                      ?  () async {   
                           setState(() {
                             isEnable = true;
                           });              
                          var url = Uri.parse(
                              '${ApiConstants.baseUrl}${ApiConstants.updateEndpoint}');
                          var responseData = await http.put(url,
                              headers: ApiConstants.headers);
              
                          if (responseData.statusCode == 202) {
                            print(jsonDecode(responseData.body).toString());
                            // ignore: use_build_context_synchronously
                            Navigator.push(
                              context,
                              MaterialPageRoute(
                                  builder: (context) => Dashboard(
                                        data: widget.data,
                                      )),
                            );
                         
                          }
                         //FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus!.unfocus();
                         //  });
                          // setState(() {
                          //  isEnable = false;
                          //   });
                      }
                      :null,
                
                 // : () {},
                  icon: const Icon(
                    Icons.home_filled,
                  ),
                  label: const Text('Entry',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                      )),
                ),
```

Comment: If onPressed and onLongPress callbacks are null, then the button will be disabled.

Comment: i have done callback as null. but still its not disabling

Comment: It seems to me that you forget to setState.or other mistake. I wrote based on the flutter document https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ElevatedButton-class.html

Comment: i have written setState . can you please make the corrections from the above code and send

Comment: @nandayelgar Where is `isEnable` defined? is it within your `build` method?

Comment: bool isEnable = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

Comment: it is outside the build

Comment: @nandayelgar Did my edit help?

Comment: @MendelG  no it did not

Answer (score 0):

Apply this code bellow:
You got error on *double equal*.

**bool variable:**

```
bool isDisabled = false;
```

**Widget**

```
      ElevatedButton.icon(
                 style: ButtonStyle(
                    backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(
                        const Color.fromARGB(255, 53, 121, 87)),
                    padding:
                        MaterialStateProperty.all(const EdgeInsets.all(20)),
                    textStyle: MaterialStateProperty.all(const TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 14, color: Colors.black))),
                onPressed: qrdata.code != 9 && !isDisabled 
                    ?  () async {   
                         setState(() {
                           isDisabled = true;
                         });              
                        var url = Uri.parse(
                            '${ApiConstants.baseUrl}${ApiConstants.updateEndpoint}');
                        var responseData = await http.put(url,
                            headers: ApiConstants.headers);

                        if (responseData.statusCode == 202) {
                          print(jsonDecode(responseData.body).toString());
                          // ignore: use_build_context_synchronously
                          Navigator.push(
                            context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (context) => Dashboard(
                                      data: widget.data,
                                    )),
                          );
                       
                        }
                        });
                         setState(() {
                         isDisabled = false;
                           });
                    }
                    :null,
```

Comment: its not working

Comment: AbsorbPointer disables buttons with out allowing to click once also, what i want is user to click once and then disable

Comment: Once the button is clicked the button would disabled at the same time?

Comment: Yes you can achieve that, uncomment your variable enable. Make that code just like this AbsorbPointer(
              absorbing:  isEnable ,
              child: CustomButton(
                  text: 'Next',
                  height: 50,
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  btnColor: Colors.amber,
                  textColor: Colors.white,
                  onTap: () {
                    FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus!.unfocus();                  }),
            ),

Comment: yes once the button gets clicked it should go in disable  mode

Comment: If I were you, use loading screen to prevent the user from clicking the button.

Comment: even after loading the screen button will comeup right? after certain time, then the user will click the same button.

Comment: Then pop the screen after success or show dialog 'Success' then if he close that dialog the screen will pop.

Comment: if he close that dialog the screen will pop.??? meaning of this

Comment: I found your mistake

Comment: See my comment again then try. Find your mistake

Comment: @ Ruel Ybañez  ok i corrected the code... but callback should be disabled. i mean button should go in inactive mode.

Comment: Just remove the setstate  after fetching or saving data

Comment: May I see your updated code?

Comment: i removed setState ,, but still allows me to click button..its not getting inactive

Comment: i have updated the code ...pls check

Comment: how do i stop callback happening??

Comment: once i click button state is setting to false and again coming back to true state.... it should actually stay in false mode.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure variable `qrdata.code` and `isEnable` are initialized outside the build method. Every time when setState is called one or both the variables are getting reset.

The problem is whenever setState is pressed it is not rebuilding the button state. so to change the button state wrap your button with [StatefulBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulBuilder-class.html).

and please call your API in `try catch`.

[image]

```
class DisableButton extends StatefulWidget {
  const DisableButton({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<DisableButton> createState() => _DisableButtonState();
}

class _DisableButtonState extends State<DisableButton> {
  bool isEnable = false;
  int qrdata = 1;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: StatefulBuilder(
          builder:
              (BuildContext context, void Function(void Function()) setState) {
            return ElevatedButton.icon(
              style: ButtonStyle(
                  backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(
                      const Color.fromARGB(255, 53, 121, 87)),
                  padding: MaterialStateProperty.all(const EdgeInsets.all(20)),
                  textStyle: MaterialStateProperty.all(
                      const TextStyle(fontSize: 14, color: Colors.black))),
              onPressed: qrdata != 9 && !isEnable
                  ? () async {
                      setState(() {
                        isEnable = true;
                      });
                      print(">>>> Button is disabled");
                      try {
                        final data = await http.get(
                          Uri.parse(
                              'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums/1'),
                        );

                        if (!mounted) return;

                        Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => NextPage(
                              data: data.body.toString(),
                            ),
                          ),
                        );

                        print("Api Data >>>> $data.body");
                      } catch (e) {
                        print("Error While fetching data");
                      }
                      setState(() {
                        isEnable = false;
                      });
                      print(">>>> Button is enabled");
                    }
                  : null,

              // : () {},
              icon: const Icon(
                Icons.home_filled,
              ),
              label: Text(isEnable ? "Disabled" : "Enabled",
                  style: const TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                  )),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class NextPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const NextPage({Key? key, required this.data}) : super(key: key);
  final String data;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Center(child: Text("Data : $data")),
    );
  }
}
```

The problem in your code is setting `isEnable` to true but not resting to false.

```
ElevatedButton.icon(
                  style: ButtonStyle(
                      backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(
                          const Color.fromARGB(255, 53, 121, 87)),
                      padding:
                          MaterialStateProperty.all(const EdgeInsets.all(20)),
                      textStyle: MaterialStateProperty.all(const TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 14, color: Colors.black))),
                  onPressed: qrdata.code != 9 && !isEnable 
                      ?  () async {   
                           setState(() {
                             isEnable = true;
                           });              
                          var url = Uri.parse(
                              '${ApiConstants.baseUrl}${ApiConstants.updateEndpoint}');
                          var responseData = await http.put(url,
                              headers: ApiConstants.headers);
              
                          if (responseData.statusCode == 202) {
                            print(jsonDecode(responseData.body).toString());
                            // ignore: use_build_context_synchronously
                            Navigator.push(
                              context,
                              MaterialPageRoute(
                                  builder: (context) => Dashboard(
                                        data: widget.data,
                                      )),
                            );
                         
                          }
                         //FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus!.unfocus();
                         //  });
                          // setState(() {  <---- Uncomment this code.
                          //  isEnable = false;
                          //   });
                      }
                      :null,
                
                 // : () {},
                  icon: const Icon(
                    Icons.home_filled,
                  ),
                  label: const Text('Entry',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                      )),
                ),
```

Comment: yes they are initialized outside build method

Comment: @nandayelgar can you please add more details to your code because the code you have provided is wrong in so many ways. Please add the proper code in which you are currently facing the issue with the variable. Thanks. and please make sure if you are getting any errors in the console please add them.

Comment: i have updated code please check..

Comment: @nandayelgar I have updated working code please check

Comment: @ Harsimran Singh button is not going in inactive mode... i mean state is not setting to false

Comment: @nandayelgar can you please confirm your API is not throwing any errors? and please wrap your API with try-catch. Let me know

Comment: there are no errors and yes wrapped it wit try catch

Comment: Please add a print statement and check if you are able to reach the end of the code or not. And I updated one mistake of yours in the code please check.

Comment: please check now i have updated the modified code

Comment: add a screenshot of your code. and did you test your code with stateful builder.

Comment: on Text widget isEnable? enable : disable not working